# Trying to map with Objects.key.map() without success

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to print my cart status in a JSX table without success.

I have this Object output in `state` Chrome Console:

```
{
  "cartItems": {
    "5": {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "Aut assumenda.",
      "price": 526,
      "quantity": 1,
      "attributes": [],
      "conditions": [],
      "associatedModel": {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Aut assumenda.",
        "description": "Nihil quisquam hic voluptatem consequuntur nemo et amet rerum.",
        "price": "526",
        "created_at": "2020-11-25T22:43:32.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-11-25T22:43:32.000000Z"
      }
    },
    "6": {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "Non est consequatur.",
      "price": 453,
      "quantity": 1,
      "attributes": [],
      "conditions": [],
      "associatedModel": {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Non est consequatur.",
        "description": "Facilis itaque ut reiciendis blanditiis maxime corrupti voluptatem.",
        "price": "453",
        "created_at": "2020-11-25T22:43:32.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-11-25T22:43:32.000000Z"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to print the object properties with Object.keys.map() method like so:

```js
{
    Object.keys(cartItems).map((item, i) => {
        return ( <
            tr key = {i} >
            <td scope="row">{item.name}</td>
            <td>{item.price}</td>
            <td>{item.quantity}</td>
            </tr>
        );
    })
}
```

Yet I cannot correctly print my cart table. I have been playing around with console log and I can't find the solution for this. It does surely have a simplem solution but I'm new to Javascript it is not evident for me in relation to my expertise.

If I `console.log(item)` inside the map method I'd get the object names which in this case are `5`and `6`.

Thank you all

Comment: You are trying to loop only the keys. Just try `cartItems.map((item, i) => {`.

Comment: I'm not sure, but you can't use Object.keys inside the render function

Comment: Thanks, it does gives more options to solving my question. However, @Passersby answer was the shortest solution without having to rewrite all the code. I don't know why people voted it down.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `Object.values(cartItems)`

```
{Object.values(cartItems).map((cartItem, i) => {
                        return (
                            <tr key={i}>
                                <td scope="row">{cartItem.name}</td>
                                <td>{cartItem.price}</td>
                                <td>{cartItem.quantity}</td>
                            </tr>
                        );
                    })}
```

Comment: This was the correct anwser. I wasn't aware of the `value()` method which is self explicative.

Answer (score -2):

`Object.keys` returns, as it name states, the keys of the object you pass as an argument. Since what you need are the key-value pairs, you should do the following:

```
{Object.keys(cartItems).map(i => {
                        const item = cartItems[i];
                        return (
                            <tr key={i}>
                                <td scope="row">{item.name}</td>
                                <td>{item.price}</td>
                                <td>{item.quantity}</td>
                            </tr>
                        );
                    })}
```